# Jenkins workspace not shown for concurrent builds on different nodes

Tags: jenkins, windows-7

**I have one job and two slave nodes. "Workspace" is shown in job overview, but it contains only "Workspace of job on slave2".** I run two builds on this job in parallel (one build runs on slave1 and one on slave2)

I tried Jenkins 2.74 and 1.658. I use Windows7 for server and slave. I configured Jenkins Job to "Execute concurrent builds if necessary". Description says

> Each concurrently executed build occurs in its own build workspace, isolated from any other builds. By default, Jenkins appends "@" to the workspace directory name, e.g. "@2".
>   The separator "@" can be changed by setting the hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList Java system property when starting Jenkins. For example, "hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=-" would change the separator to a hyphen.

I also use "Restrict where this project can be run" with: slave1||slave2

How can i display links to all workspaces of all configured slaves at the same time in jenkins web interface, i thought they will be shown as workspace@1 and so on?